# how to get my datetime string converted by logstash and populate into elasticsearch

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to use the first csv field as a timestamp in elastic search, which is getting populated by logstash. but i never see them in elastic search. I don't even see my index "network" in elastic search. I have tried with +0000 and +000 for the format.

Here is a couple lines in my log file.

```
2021/07/28 14:39:59.102;DEBUG;10063;0;main@146;"Sending response"
2021/07/28 15:09:59.102;DEBUG;10063;0;main@146;"Sending response"
```

here is my config file for logstash.

```
input {
file {
path => "/tmp/gold.out"
start_position => "beginning"
}
}

filter {
csv {
separator => ";"
skip_header => "true"
columns => [ "datetime", "level", "pid", "thread", "object", "log_string" ]
}
date {
locale => "en"
timezone => "GMT"
match => ["datetime", "yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss +0000"]
}
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
index => "network"
}
}
```

Comment: The pattern should be "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS". Are you appending to that file? Since you are persisting the sincedb it may already have read the file on a previous run. Setting sincedb_path => "/dev/null" might, or might not, help.

Comment: So that got me close. however it is taking 2021/07/28 and converting it to January 28, 2021. The time is correct, the day is correct and the year is correct.

Jan 28, 2021 @ 12:49:59.102 @timestamp:Jan 28, 2021 @ 12:49:59.102

here is the date config.

date {
locale => "en"
timezone => "GMT"
match => ["datetime", "yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
}
}

Comment: MM and mm are different things.

Comment: yes they are. Thanks.